# JS filter nested array by element field value

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, filter, nested

I want to filter a nested array by element field value. Here is the array need to filter.
I want to filter by element checked value, If value equal true, return, false, discard the element.

```
let rawData =[
      {
        name: 'red',
        checked: true,
        children: [
          {
            name: 'red1',
            checked: false,
            children: [
              {
                name: 'red11',
                checked: true,
                children: [
                  {
                    name: 'red111',
                    checked: false,
                    children: [
                      {
                        name: 'red1111',
                        checked: true,
                        children: []
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'blue',
        checked: false,
        children: [
          {
            name: 'blue1',
            checked: true,
            children: [
              {
                name: 'blue11',
                checked: true,
                children: []
              },
               {
                name: 'blue12',
                checked: false,
                children: []
              },
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
       name: 'yellow',
       checked: false,
       children: []
      }
    ]
```

Here is the result i want.
(Filter every element and return it with checked equal true.
If not equal true, just discard.

```
 let result =[
      {
        name: 'red',
        checked: true,
        children: [
          {
            name: 'red11',
            checked: true,
            children: [
              {
                name: 'red1111',
                checked: true,
                children: []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]   
      },
        {
          name: 'blue1',
          checked: true,
          children: [
            {
              name: 'blue11',
              checked: true,
              children: []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
```

---

Here is my solution. (won't work)

```
let result = rawData.filter(node => {
  function getCheckedData (node) {
    if (node.checked === true) {
      return node
    }
    if (node.children.length) {
      node.children.filter(c => {
        getCheckedData(c)
      })
    }
   return getCheckedData(node)
})
```

`node.children.filter` never execute if first level data `checked equal true`.
What should i do to make make `children` recursive go on no matter `parent` checked status.
Thanks~~

Comment: Are you actually trying to support the checked value of the string `"false"`? What do you expect that to equate to? True? False?

Comment: There is something odd about your requirements.  You're returning a tree, but the output structure is only slightly related to the input one.  In the input, `red1111` is a *grandchild* of `red11`.  But in the output it's a *child*.  Are you sure you don't want a flat list for the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not account for your use of `checked: 'false',` which is a truthy value but is the word false... so ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ I'll assume literal false.

```js
let rawData =[
      {
        name: 'red',
        checked: true,
        children: [
          {
            name: 'red1',
            //checked: 'false', // ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
            checked: false,
            children: [
              {
                name: 'red11',
                checked: true,
                children: [
                  {
                    name: 'red111',
                    checked: false,
                    children: [
                      {
                        name: 'red1111',
                        checked: true,
                        children: []
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'blue',
        checked: false,
        children: [
          {
            name: 'blue1',
            checked: true,
            children: [
              {
                name: 'blue11',
                checked: true,
                children: []
              },
               {
                name: 'blue12',
                checked: false,
                children: []
              },
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
       name: 'yellow',
       checked: false,
       children: []
      }
    ];

function checkedStuff(arr) {
  return arr.flatMap(
    a => a.checked
    ? {...a, children: checkedStuff(a.children)}
    : checkedStuff(a.children)
  );
}

console.log(checkedStuff(rawData));
```

Comment: a beautiful use of `flatMap` and recursion